# Why is my program creating a 10x9 grid instead of a 10x10 grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code works from a functionality standpoint. I want to create a "drawing pad" in that it creates a grid of small 'divs' that change color when the mouse goes over them. The 'divs' change color - but I don't understand why it is creating a 10 x 9 grid instead of a 10 x 10 grid?

```js
// When the document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Do some things...
  newGrid(10); // create a new 10 x 10 grid
  $(".block").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  });
});

function newGrid(gridNum) {
  var maxDivs = gridNum * gridNum;
  var currentDivNum = 1; // Current number of divs; will have 100 total by default

  while (currentDivNum <= maxDivs) {
    // While the current div number is less than max divs...
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'block'; // set the class name of the divisions
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if (currentDivNum % gridNum == 0) { 
      div.style.float = 'clear';
      div.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    } else {
      div.style.float = 'left';
      div.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    }
    div.style.width = '25px';
    div.style.height = '25px';

    document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(div);

    currentDivNum++;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divContainer"></div>
```

Comment: can you create a small working snippet, the code given appears to be ok

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afhkc6xg/ thought i'd try.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find this working example, just insert a clear div after each 10:

```js
// When the document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
// Do some things...
newGrid(10); // create a new 10 x 10 grid
    $(".block").hover(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});

function newGrid(gridNum) {

var maxDivs = gridNum * gridNum;
var currentDivNum = 1; // Current number of divs; will have 100 total by default

while (currentDivNum <= maxDivs) {
    // While the current div number is less than max divs...

    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'block'; // set the class name of the divisions
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  
    div.style.float = 'left';
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
  
    div.style.width = '25px';
    div.style.height = '25px';

    document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(div);
  
    if (currentDivNum % gridNum == 0) { 
      clearDiv = document.createElement('div');
      clearDiv.style.clear = 'both';
      
      document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(clearDiv);

    } 
  

    currentDivNum++;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divContainer"></div>
```

**Explanation**

`div.style.float = 'clear';` is not valid, since float does not take clear as a value, so what you really need is to enter a div where it clears the float for both left and right i.e `Both` and this is added after each `X` divs :

```
if (currentDivNum % gridNum == 0) { 
          clearDiv = document.createElement('div');
          clearDiv.style.clear = 'both';

          document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(clearDiv);

        }
```

Apart of that, the code enters divs in a normal manner..

Comment: This creates an extra div unnecessarily.  The clear and float can be applied to the same div, see my answer below.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now... I knew I was close - but, as you found, I was missing something. You saved me a day full of wondering.

Comment: @dave, you have a point dude, it is adding an extra div... Both work fine though, no complexity to worry about here ;)

Answer (score 4):

Following is not valid:

```
 div.sytle.float = 'clear';
```

See working JSFiddle that corrects the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cwpxy8dv/

The solution is to keep all items floating left, and go to the next row by applying clear left for every tenth item.

Key part of the solution is the following snippet:

```
div.style.float = 'left'; // set for all grid divs
if ( (currentDivNum-1) % gridNum == 0) { // use currentDivNum-1 since it starts at 1
  div.style.clear = 'left';  // clear to next row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes in your code:

```
while (currentDivNum < maxDivs) {
```

and

```
if (currentDivNum % (gridNum+1) == 0) {
```

The reason your problem occured was that at every tenth square, CSS code `clear:both;` was added, which meant that it started on a new line. My improvement has given this feature to every eleventh square which is what you needed.

In addition to that, it was necessary to remove one last square, which would appear on the last (new) line. That's why the `while` part is also updated.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `if` and `else` and cause the performance down if `div`s are large in number. Use below code with fixes applied and for performance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do some things...
    newGrid(10); // create a new 10 x 10 grid
    $(".block").hover(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});

function newGrid(gridNum) {
    var maxDivs = gridNum * gridNum;
    var currentDivNum = 1; // Current number of divs; will have 100 total by default
    var divWidth = 25;
    var divHeight = 25;
    var container =  document.getElementById('divContainer');
    container.style.width = (divWidth * gridNum)+'px';
  
    while (currentDivNum <= maxDivs) {
        // While the current div number is less than max divs...
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'block'; // set the class name of the divisions
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    
        div.style.float = 'left';
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
        div.style.width = divWidth+'px';
        div.style.height = divHeight+'px';
  
        div.style.color = '#fff';
        div.innerHTML = currentDivNum;
       
        container.appendChild(div);     

        currentDivNum++;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes, so far I've changed the counter, now start at 0.

`clear` isn't a value of css property, it's the property itself like:

```
.myclass {
 clear: left;
}
```

Here is the working code:

```
// When the document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
    // create a new 10 x 10 grid
    newGrid(10); 

    $(".block").hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});

function newGrid(gridNum) {
    var maxDivs = gridNum * gridNum;

    // Current number of divs will have 100 total by default
    var currentDivNum = 0; 

    while (currentDivNum < maxDivs) {
        // While the current div number is less than max divs...
        div = document.createElement('div');

        // set the class name of the divisions
        div.className = 'block'; 

        // Set background color
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        div.style.float = 'left';

        div.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';

        if ((currentDivNum % gridNum) == 0)
            div.style.clear = 'left';

        div.style.width = div.style.height = '25px';

        document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(div);

        currentDivNum++;
    }
}
```

Here is a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/40cywo6L/2/)